# Java applet sound in HTML

Tags: java, html, audio, applet, javasound

Just a quick question about a program I've been working on. I've made an applet that has several sounds that play depending on the users input that all work fine when I run it through Eclipse. The problem is when I have the code embedded into the HTML, one of the sounds that should run for about 2secs when user completes the game, instead cuts out almost immediately.

What might be causing this?

Comment: 1) *"What might be causing this?"*  Might be the code.  Got an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)?  2) The problem seems like it would go away if the applet were a frame being launched by [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  3) Got (or can make) an URL where we can visit the misbehaving applet?

Comment: hey not looked at this the last while but seem to have it working now...i put the source code into a jar file and since then the sound has been playing ok...im not going to question it